# Is "influence of stg on stg" equal to "influence on stg of stg"?

Tags: word-order

Can we say "It shows how strong is the influence on children of tv " instead of "It shows how strong is the influence of tv on children"?

Comment: Neither of those sentences is grammatical (there should be no subject-auxiliary inversion), but the first one also sounds like you’re talking about children of tv and how influential they are, which is something very different from how much of an influence tv has on children.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Seems like a stylistic preference to me, not a grammatical error.

Comment: @aparente001 I presume you’re talking about the reversal of the prepositional phrases, not the subject-auxiliary inversion? Because that is definitely ungrammatical to me, in the same way that _I wonder how old is he_ or _We need to find out what are they doing_ are both ungrammatical to me.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - I'd agree with you in rejecting "find out what are they doing,"  but your "wonder" example evokes Mother Goose -- it's a certain style, sure, it's unusual, but I wouldn't call it *wrong*. // The OP does seem to have been asking about the order of the prepositional phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can swap the order, but it is unusual.  “Influence of stg on stg” is much more common.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to English stackexchange.

Unfortunately neither sentence is grammatically correct, as pointed out by @Janus Baths Jacquet.

The sentence should be written, "It shows how strong the influence of tv is on children".

Comment: I think you missed what OP is trying to ask.